# Jackson serialize without properties

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have a json structure like this:

```
{
    "name": "LS",
    "stocks": [
      {
        "x": 1500234365000,
        "y": 0.000000000000
      },
      {
        "x": 1500234427000,
        "y": 0.000015154000
      },
      {
        "x": 1500234481000,
        "y": 0.000015518740
      },
      {
        "x": 1500234548000,
        "y": 0.008415518740
      }
    ]
 }
```

But i need that my json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "LS",
    "stocks": [
      [1500234365000,0.000000000000],
      [1500234427000,0.000015154000],
      [1500234481000,0.000015518740],
      [1500234548000,0.008415518740]
    ]
 }
```

My mapping class:

```
public class View implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1636349140413063122L;

    @Getter @Setter
    private String name;

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
    @Getter @Setter
    private List<Data> rates = new ArrayList<Data>();
}
```

And Data array:

```
public class Data implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2926346626990185211L;

    @JsonProperty("x")
    @Getter @Setter
    private Long date;

    @JsonProperty("y")
    @Getter @Setter
    private BigDecimal value;
```

There's any native way to do it? I search trough stackoverflow and jackson documentation but found nothing how to remove the properties name.

Don't know if its possible too.

Anyway, im using spring boot with jackson

Comment: That's just a 2D array, no?

Comment: Jolt is great for stuff like this: https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt

Comment: If you want the JSON field to be named `stocks`, don't name the Java field `rates`, and if you want the JSON value to be an array of arrays (2D array), then don't make the Java field a `List` of bean objects, but make it a list of lists, or list of arrays, or array of array. Then you won't have to write a custom serializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can  customize a json serialized class

```
public class MyStdSerializer extends StdSerializer<Data> {

    public MyStdSerializer(){
        this(null);
    }
    public MyStdSerializer(Class<Data> t) {
        super(t);
    }


    @Override
    public void serialize(Data value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {

        jgen.writeStartArray();
        jgen.writeNumber(value.getDate());
        jgen.writeNumber(value.getValue());
        jgen.writeEndArray();

    }

}
```

and then :

```
@JsonSerialize(using=MyStdSerializer.class)
public class Data implements Serializable{

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 2926346626990185211L;

        @JsonProperty("x")
        private Long date;

        @JsonProperty("y")
        private BigDecimal value;

        public Long getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(Long date) {
            this.date = date;
        }

        public BigDecimal getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(BigDecimal value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

You can write a [custom serializer](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization)  for the Data class

```
public class ItemSerializer extends StdSerializer<Item> {
     
    public ItemSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }
   
    public ItemSerializer(Class<Item> t) {
        super(t);
    }
 
    @Override
    public void serialize(
      Item value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
  
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeNumberField("id", value.id);
        jgen.writeStringField("itemName", value.itemName);
        jgen.writeNumberField("owner", value.owner.id);
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

To write an array you have to use `writeStartArray` and `writeEndArray`

```
    jgen.writeStartArray();
    jgen.writeNumber(id);
    jgen.writeNumber(number1);
    jgen.writeEndArray();
```

Array write example is from [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator&method=writeStartArray).

And then use it as annotation on your class:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ItemSerializer.class)
public class Item {}
```

**Option 2**

The other way to approach the problem is to make another class(like DTO) that represents the exact structure and naming that you need in the json. Then you can first map your current objects to the new one(the DTO) and serialize the DTO.

Actually I would go with the second approach because:

1) It's more obvious what is going on. With the StdSerializer approach the reader of your code has to spot the usage of the custom reader and may not be familiar with the technology, etc.

2) If you use these classes as return types of some rest api and use jackson to serialize them(like Spring MVC) and you have to use some rest documentation tool like Swagger, it will work way better with the DTO approach and may not work at all with the custom serializers.